# What is a good database for storing boolean logic rules

Tags: database-design

Very new so forgive my naivete. I have a series of clinical guidelines that might look something like pseudocode below. As far as I can tell they can be represented as decision trees.

Each decision uses very different variables that are called from a patient information database (I'm thinking of just using PostgreSQL FHIR for that). As you can imagine these guidelines are quite lengthy so I don't think it makes sense to hardcode it. I thought storing it in a database would make more sense. I explored some options e.g. using neo4j graph databases. If anyone has any advice on how they think decision rules like this should be stored and called, I would really appreciate any pointers.

```
IF age > 15
  IF ischaemic heart disease == TRUE
    IF sex == male AND age < 55
      assessFHScore()
    ELSEIF sex == female AND age < 60 years
  ELSEIF (total cholesterol > 7.5  OR ldl-cholesterol > 4.9
    assessFHScore()
  ELSE
    return
```

Comment: These don't appear to be something you should store in a database, at least not as decision tree branches. Perhaps the individual properties in each branch for your objects can be stored in tables though. What do you plan to do with these logic branches?...I'm assuming you want to actually use them in code somewhere so that they're functional?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just thought it would make more sense if there are lots of decision rules to make it more 'modular' or easy to update/change versus hard-coding it? If you look at the PDF here, this is what I am trying to 'automate'. As you can probably appreciate there are 100s of mini decision rules. As an example if you navigate to page 25, you can see examples of the decision rules. https://www.racgp.org.au/download/Documents/Guidelines/Redbook9/17048-Red-Book-9th-Edition.pdf